# How do I define the variable 'age'?

Tags: jquery

CodeAcademy says that I did not define the variable age?

Where did I go wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    confirm("I am ready to play!");
    var age = prompt("What's your age");

    if (age > 18) {
    console.log("play on player");
    }
    else {
    console.log("you are not allow to play bro");
    }
    });
```

*For anyone that is wondering why I don't use the CA Q&A, is because Stack people are quicker and more entertaining.

Comment: One does not simply define age.

Answer (score 2):

`else (` is not valid syntax.  You need `else if` (or just `else {`).  Otherwise the code looks okay to me, so maybe just a CA bug?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work better, note that you were missing an `if` statement

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    confirm("I am ready to play!");

    var age = prompt("What's your age");

    if (age > 18) {
     console.log("play on player");
    }else{
     if(age < 18) {      //but what about age == 18?? :)
      console.log("you are not allow to play");
     }
    }
});
```

**Edit**

In response to your edit. If this code above runs, and you try later to access `age` you will not be able to, because `age` is scoped to this "closure" (function scope). If you want to have access later, you should try this:

```
var age;
$(document).ready(function(){
 confirm("I am ready to play!");

 age = prompt("What's your age");

 if (age > 18) {
  console.log("play on player");
 }else{
  console.log("you are not allow to play");
 }
});
```

So now later you will be able to use the `age` variable. *However*, if you had not taken this approach, went with the first approach, and tried `console.log(age)` outside of your `$(document).ready)` block, you would get an exception that `age` was not defined.

Comment: I think this is the correct solution but CA still says that 'age' is undefined - thank you for the help I will take it up with them.

Comment: @JoeIsaacson - In this scenario, `age` will be undefined on page load, because the user has not entered it. If you set age to something like "test" in the first assignment, you would see "test" on page load. That is because `document.ready` waits until the page loads to run your script. And then the user has to input the value for `age`.

Comment: @JoeIsaacson - So, if you used `var age = "test";` it would be "test" until the user assigned it from the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        confirm("I am ready to play!");
        var age = prompt("What's your age");

        if (age > 18) {
        console.log("play on player");
        }
        else if(age < 18) {
        console.log("you are not allow to play dawg");
        }
        });
```

you made a simple typo and should've put `else if(` instead of `else`

Comment: ah. Thank you fo pointing that out @darwayne but CA says 'age' is still undefined. Maybe it is an error on their end.

Comment: yep, it is more than likely an error on their end because the else portion is the only error in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay but

You should do [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) on your age before comparison because ATM you're comparing string with int type.

And you should do something if your visitor is 18 :P have something like:
`if( age.parseInt() >= 18)`

or you could do before comparing `age = age.parseInt()`

Comment: the main problem here is that CA says 'age' is undefined (but it IS)

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of `age` looks ok though you might like to perform an explicit conversion from String to Number.

Also `confirm()` is pointless unless the returned value is  tested.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(confirm("I am ready to play!")) {
        var age = Number(prompt("What's your age"));
        if (age >= 18) {
            console.log("play on player");
        }
        else {
            console.log("you are not allow to play bro");
        }
    }
});
```